# Opening a new window JFrame when selecting an item in JList and click a button

Tags: java, sql, swing, jlist

Im trying to open a new window when selecting an item from `Jlist` and clicking a button but I got an error that says can't find symbol... I'm using the same code from my previous form and i already set my Label to public static so it can show the value but still this error occurs in `dateInPostStatus` and `postInPostStatus`.

`dateInPostStatus` and `postInPostStatus` are my labels

here are the errors

```
 cannot find symbol
 symbol: variable dateInPostStatus 
 location: variable dateInPostStatus of type JPanel

 cannot find symbol                      
 symbol: variable postInPostStatus
 location: variable postInPostStatus of type JPanel
```

Code:

```
private void commentOnPostButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    int index = showPostStatus.getSelectedIndex();

    if(index != -1)
    {
        String sql1 = "select * from Post where postInfo=?"; 
        String value = (String)showPostStatus.getSelectedValue();
        try
        {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pst.setString(1,value);

            rs = pst.executeQuery();          

            PostStatus r = new PostStatus();

            String getDate= rs.getString("datePostCreated");
            PostStatus.dateInPostStatus.setText(getDate);

            String getPost= rs.getString("post");
            PostStatus.postInPostStatus.setText(getPost);

            rs.close();
            pst.close();
            r.setVisible(true);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }

    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a Post to comment!");
}
```

Comment: can you please post full stack trace ?

Comment: im sorry what is a full stack trace?

Comment: i mean can you post your full error statement?

Comment: Why are we making static calls with `PostStatus` when we have an instance `r` ?

Comment: looking at your error it seems like dateInPostStatus and postInPostStatus labels is not resolved at the place where you are using. Can you please post those lines where these variables are used ?

Comment: the object r replacing PostStatus did the trick! im stupid at debugging thank you very much Sanket Pipariya and  peeskillet for the help!

Comment: If your `postInDateStatus` is of `JPanel`, type then for your information, `JPanel` has no `setText()` method.